# integration Froala editir in livewire 3

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

In Livewire 3 after editing another field the component refreshed and froala editor disappeared.
How I can solve this problem:

```
<label for="" class="block">
<p>body</p>
<div id="editor" wire:model="body" class="w-full h-96"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `wire:ignore` for the `#editor`'s parent div:

```
    <label for="" class="block">
         <p>body</p>
         <div wire:ignore> 
            <div id="editor" wire:model="body" class="w-full h-96"></div>
         </div>
    </label>
```

Comment: Yes but totally ignore body value.